# Unit testing with Optionals - Spring Boot and JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, mockito

[image]

Hey guys. I am trying to test a method that returns an *Optional*. I am using Spring Boot and JUnit, however, in the thenReturn method it doesn't allow me to return an *Optional*. I also tried it without *Optional.of()*. What is the best way to test Optionals? Thanks

Comment: You already have Optional<UserEntity>, which can be directly passed to thenReturn. You are wrapping it in another Optional, thus creating Optional<Optional<UserEntity>> - the compiler flags this as an error. You need to show the signature of repo method to explain why the variant without Optional.of fails. Ideally, full error message as well. As a side note: please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I would copy your code to provide a more in-depth answer with working code, but it is an image, so the code cannot be copied.

You have an Optional and wrap it in another Optional. That's a different type and cannot be returned by your method. Either have your UserUtil not return an Optional, but the plain value or don't wrap it again when setting up the stubbing of your mock object.